# Как повысить скорость приема изображения с экрана OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм, opencv

У меня есть код, который в постоянном режиме просматривает области на экране и выполняет определенные действия. Но это происходит относительно долго. Каким образом можно повысить скорость работы кода.

```
while True:
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()

    frame = np.array(screenshot)

    edges = cv2.Canny(frame, 300, 200)
    
    # Дальше функция проверяет определенные области экрана
    if not check_for_edges(edges[361:371, 1071:1084], 1369, 387):
        break

    if not check_for_edges(edges[541:551, 1071:1084], 1369, 470):
        break

    if not check_for_edges(edges[721:731, 1071:1084], 1369, 551):
        break

    if not check_for_edges(edges[901:911, 1074:1086], 1369, 632):
        break

    if not check_for_edges(edges[1081:1091, 1071:1084], 1369, 713):
        break

    if not check_for_edges(edges[1261:1271, 1164:1176], 1369, 794):
        break

    if not check_for_edges(edges[1441:1451, 1164:1176], 1369, 875):
        break
```

Функция check_for_edges:

```
def check_for_edges(edges, x, y):
    if cv2.countNonZero(edges) > 0:
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        pyautogui.click(buy_x, buy_y)
        cntn = input()
        if cntn not in ["y", "н"]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: canny небыстрая функция, я в C++ распараллеливаю обработку, если многоядерный процессор, использую tbb::parallel_pipeline, tbb вроде есть для питона, но не уверен, насколько он рабочий

Comment: ещё можно попробовать через GPU, для этого frame наверное надо перевести в `cv.UMat`

Comment: хорошо, попробую

Comment: попытался установить tbb для питона, устанавливаю, пишет, что установлен, но не импортируется (модель не найден). Python 3.11

Comment: не могу ничего сказать, может быть oneAPI надо установить? может он tbb dll-и оттуда хочет...

Comment: Я вроде бы нашел способ как выделять контуры изображения, сейчас реализую, может ли быть большая задержка в постоянно делании скриншотов? Смотрел можно сделать захват экрана с помощью vidgear

Comment: в opencv есть встроенный profiler, им можно изучить куда время уходит, https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Profiling-OpenCV-Applications см. раздел `Alternative collection of trace information for custom analyzing`

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с моим ответом здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1526891/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-opencv-%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83